# How to create a group with special characters using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been tasked with creating a number of active directory groups using PowerShell.  The problem is all the group names contain double colons "::" (the naming standard was created long before I joined!).

When running the following command:

```
NEW-ADGroup –name "XX123::Test_Group_Creation" –groupscope Global –path "OU=TestOU,DC=TestDomain,DC=local"
```

The following error is received:

> NEW-ADGroup : The name provided is not a properly formed account name
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + NEW-ADGroup –name "XX123::Test_Group_Creation" –groupscope Global –path "OU=Test ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=XX123::Test_...Domain,DC=local:String) [New-ADGroup], ADException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The server is unwilling to process the request,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup

If you create the group manually (in the gui) you get the following warning but you are still able to create it:

[image]

How can I get around this issue.  F.Y.I. I have tried to escape the colons with a back tick and also a forward slash, none of which have worked

Comment: Read the GUI error message very carefully. It is telling you that the "pre-Windows 2000 group name" contains illegal characters. That is the `sAMAccountName` attribute. This means that when you use `New-ADGroup`, you must not use those characters in that attrbiute or replace them with `_` characters (which the GUI will politely do for you after informing you of such).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart.  Thanks for that.  If I do a     `get-adgroup groupname -properties *` on an already created group the     `samAccountname` attribute indeed is replaced with underscores, however there is a     `name` attribute that still has the colons.  I think my question is how do I amend the    `name` attribute

Comment: The colons are valid in `name` but not `sAMAccountName`. So you only have to change `sAMAccountName` so it works in AD.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using characters that aren't allowed in file and folder names in a user or group name.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart.  Many thanks you were right - I had to also specify the     `samaccountname` otherwise it tried to use what was specified for     `name` for both.  Feel free to answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` character is not valid for the `sAMAccountName` attribute, so you need to replace `:` with another character (the GUI uses `_`) when creating the group. You can use the `-replace` operator to do this pretty easily in PowerShell.